# Display rows retrieved from a database in seperate textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

I have a MySQL database with about 40 rows.

I want to read "value" each into its own textbox.

What I have so far

```
using (var cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("select value,entity_id,store_id from      catalog_category_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 41 ", con))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.HasRows)
        {
            int count = reader.FieldCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    textBox[i].txt = (reader[0].ToString());

                    this.Controls.Add(textBox[i].txt);

                    reader.NextResult();

                }
            }
        }
```

I only get the first record into a textbox.

Assume that the amount of rows is unknown.
If there is 40 rows, there must be 40 textboxes.

I've edited my code to:

```
using (var reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
              {
                  int i = 0;
                  while (reader.HasRows)
                     {
                         TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                         txt.Text = reader.GetString(0);
                         this.Controls.Add(txt);

                         textBox[i].txt = (reader.GetString(0));
                         this.Controls.Add(textBox[i].txt);
                         reader.NextResult();
                         i++;
                     }
              }
```

The error that I get is : error - the name textbox does not exist in the current context

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with mysql.

Comment: I am using Mysql to get the data.

Comment: @Danie but that is irrelvant for the question.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

If your `textBox` is an array of controls

```
con.Open();  -- you need open the connection before the command

using (var cmd2 = new OdbcCommand("select value,entity_id,store_id 
                                   from catalog_category_entity_varchar 
                                   where attribute_id = 41 ", con))
{
        using (var reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Text =  reader.GetString(0);
                txt.Location.x = 100;
                txt.Location.y = 100 * i;
                this.Controls.Add(txt);
                i++;
            }
```

If you havent create the textbox already you need

```
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
txt.Text =  reader.GetValue(0);
txt.Location.x = 100;
txt.Location.y = 100 * i;
this.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Comment: I have tried that, error - the name textbox does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Do you have a `textbox` array? otherwise you need create each control as I show you.

Comment: reader.GetValue(0) gives me error Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'

Comment: The getstring works, but still getting the textbox does not exist error.

Comment: I show you how create the textbox in my code. If you dont have a `textbox` check your code